# Getting incorrect sent date/time from google api

Tags: gmail-api

I recently wrote an app that calls google's api to get a list of threads from a users inbox.  For some of the emails I'm getting an incorrect sent time.  For example, I just queried it for a user and it's currently 3:55pm EST here and yet the Date header has the value of Mon, 11 Sep 2017 19:14:53 +0000 - 7:14pm EST.  Each time I've encountered a time in the future it has the +0000 at the end of the string.  I'm assuming that's a timezone offset, but if it was, wouldn't it have a value other than 0?